# Android NFC: Reading tag does not work

Tags: android, nfc

I want to create an application that can read a tag. I copied the NFCDemo code, but that did not work. I also added

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
  <data android:mimeType="mime/type" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
  <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
    android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

to my manifest file.

But the application is never called / opened when I hold the tag at my Nexus S.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1):

To make it easy at the beginning, remove all the intent filters but the TAG_DISCOVERED one. This is the most basic one. Once the NFC chip will discover a NFC tag, it will send out and event with TAG_DISCOVERED. If you have registered teh intent filter to an activity you should then see the intent chooser with your app in it.